# React Router: props aren't passed down when directly accessing the URL of child component. Will I need to use the same state in both parent and child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, react-router

I'm pretty new to React and React Router so apologies if this is a silly question or answered elsewhere - I did a search but couldn't find a similar question.

I'm using React Router v6 and React Hooks. My very basic full-stack app is focused on keeping track of musical artists and their released projects (albums, mixtapes, EPs, etc.). My App component will render the ProjectList component at the `'/'` route, and the ArtistList component at the `'/artists'` route.

Relevant portions of App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import ProjectList from './ProjectList';
import ArtistList from './ArtistList';

import { Button } from './styles.js';

const App = () => {
  const [ projects, setProjects ] = useState([]);

  const getProjects = () => axios('projects').then(({ data }) => setProjects(data));
  useEffect(getProjects, []);

  return (<>
    <Link to="/">
      <Button>Projects</Button> // Button is using styled-components
    </Link>
    <Link to="/artists">
      <Button>Artists</Button>
    </Link>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<ProjectList projects={projects} />} />
      <Route path="/artists" element={<ArtistList projects={projects} />} />
    </Routes>
  </>);
};
```

This all works as expected when I click the Projects and Artists buttons. However, when I attempt to access the `'/artists'` route directly through the URL bar of my browser, nothing renders and I get an error about how the `projects` prop is undefined. My assumption is that because I'm trying to access the ArtistList component before rendering the App component itself, `getProjects` doesn't run and so no `projects` props are passed down to ArtistList.

I need the list of `projects` to render my ArtistList component. Each element of `projects` is an object that includes an `artist` property that I use to create my list of artist names and a `dateAdded` property that I use to sort the artist list by recency. I also keep track of how many projects each artist has.

Relevant portions of ArtistList.jsx (the `return` block contains some `styled-components` - Options, Header, TextWrapper, and Artist):

```
const ArtistList = ({ projects }) => {
  const [ artists, setArtists ] = useState([]);
  const [ sortBy, setSortBy ] = useState('name');

  const getArtists = () => {
    const artists = [];
    let curArtist = projects[0].artist;
    let projectCount = 0;
    const now = new Date();
    let firstAdded = now;

    for (const { artist, dateAdded } of projects) {
      if (artist !== curArtist) {
        artists.push({ name: curArtist, projectCount, firstAdded });
        curArtist = artist;
        projectCount = 0;
        firstAdded = now;
      }
      projectCount++;
      const projectDate = new Date(dateAdded);
      if (projectDate < firstAdded)
        firstAdded = projectDate;
    }
    setArtists(artists);
  };
  useEffect(getArtists, [ projects, sortBy ]);

  if (sortBy === 'number')
    artists.sort((a, b) => b.projectCount - a.projectCount);
  else if (sortBy === 'recency')
    artists.sort((a, b) => b.firstAdded - a.firstAdded);

  return (<>
    <Options>
      <label htmlFor="sortBy">Sort by: </label>
      <select id="sortBy" value={sortBy} onChange={e => setSortBy(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="artist">Name</option>
        <option value="number"># of Projects</option>
        <option value="recency">Recently Added</option>
      </select>
    </Options>
    <Header>
      <TextWrapper>Name</TextWrapper>
      <TextWrapper># of Projects</TextWrapper>
    </Header>
    {artists.map(({ name, projectCount }, idx) => (
      <Artist key={idx}>
        <TextWrapper>{name}</TextWrapper>
        <TextWrapper>{projectCount}</TextWrapper>
      </Artist>
    ))}
  </>);
};
```

I currently see 2 solutions to this issue (I'm sure I'm missing more):

1. Create a `projects` state and a `getProjects` in the ArtistList component, pretty much exactly as they are in the parent App component. Whenever I render ArtistList, I will make a request to my back end to retrieve a list of projects and then invoke `setProjects`. I'd then derive the `artists` state from `projects`, as before. Of course, I'd no longer need to pass the `projects` props from App to ArtistList. However, I would then have the exact same state values/functionality in both parent and child components, and this feels to me like a violation of fundamental React principles.
2. Put a collection of Artists into my Mongo database, in addition to the Projects collection I currently have. I would have to implement something similar to the `getArtists` function, but in the back end this time, then put the list of artist data into my database. Then, every time I try to render ArtistList, I will make a request to my back end to retrieve the list of artists and go from there.

The third option is doing nothing, but then I'm unable to access the `'/artists'` page directly through the URL.

What would be best practice and the best approach in this instance? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `projects` state ***is*** actually defined on the initial render cycle:

```
const [ projects, setProjects ] = useState([]);
```

So it's a defined prop when passed to `ArtistList`:

```
<Route path="/artists" element={<ArtistList projects={projects} />} />
```

The issue starts when in `ArtistList` in the `useEffect` hook calling `getArtists` where it is *incorrectly* attempting to access a property of the first element of the `projects` array which is currently an undefined object.

```
const getArtists = () => {
  const artists = [];
  let curArtist = projects[0].artist; // <-- error, access artist of undefined!
  let projectCount = 0;
  const now = new Date();
  let firstAdded = now;

  for (const { artist, dateAdded } of projects) {
    if (artist !== curArtist) {
      artists.push({ name: curArtist, projectCount, firstAdded });
      curArtist = artist;
      projectCount = 0;
      firstAdded = now;
    }
    projectCount++;
    const projectDate = new Date(dateAdded);
    if (projectDate < firstAdded)
      firstAdded = projectDate;
  }
  setArtists(artists);
};

useEffect(getArtists, [projects, sortBy]);
```

What you can do is to only run the logic in `getArtists` is the array is populated.

```
const getArtists = () => {
  const artists = [];
  let curArtist = projects[0].artist;
  let projectCount = 0;
  const now = new Date();
  let firstAdded = now;

  for (const { artist, dateAdded } of projects) {
    if (artist !== curArtist) {
      artists.push({ name: curArtist, projectCount, firstAdded });
      curArtist = artist;
      projectCount = 0;
      firstAdded = now;
    }
    projectCount++;
    const projectDate = new Date(dateAdded);
    if (projectDate < firstAdded)
      firstAdded = projectDate;
  }
  setArtists(artists);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (projects.length) {
    getArtists();
  }
}, [projects, sortBy]);
```

And to ensure that `projects` is *at least* always a defined value, provide an initial value when destructuring the prop.

```
const ArtistList = ({ projects = [] }) => { ... }
```